# How to make Zigzag plot

Tags: matlab

I want to make a zigzag plot in matlab, and have a mathematical formula. Why following does not work:

```
clc
clear all
p=100;
m=5;
x=0:1:100;

for 0 < x <= p./m
y(i) =m.*x;
end

plot(x,y)
hold on 

for p./m < x <= 2.*p./m
 y(i) = -m.*x + 2.*p ;
end

plot(x,y)
hold on 



for 2.*p./m < x <= 3.*p./m
 y(i) = m.*x - 2.*p;
end

plot(x,y)
```

Comment: If you need a zigzag - why do you not just connect the corners?

Comment: what you have wrote as you code is not using MATLAB syntax in the `for` loops. You must write something like: `for x = p/m : 2*p/m1` instead of `for p./m < x <= 2.*p./m`. MATLAB build-in documentation simply teaches you how to write loops.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in the defining of the for loop. It should be:

```
clc
clear all
p=100;
m=5;
x=0:1:100;
y=[];
y1=[];
y2=[];

for x=1: p/m
 y(end+1) =m.*x;
end

plot(x,y)
hold on 

for x=p/m+1:2*p/m
 y1(end+1) = -m.*x + 2.*p ;
end

plot(x,y1)
hold on 

for x=2*p/m+1: 3.*p./m
 y2(end+1) = m.*x - 2.*p;
end

plot(x,y2)
```

I used `y`, `y1`, `y2`, and not just `y` as in your code because if it's not the same length in all the loops, it'll be a wrong result.

---

**EDIT:**

As @Manex wtore, it's indeed doesn't produce the zigzag, becuse the plots is over `x`, and not over the proper values for each plot. Here I fixed it, and also arrange the whole code, to be more readable:

```
clc
clear all
p=100;
m=5; 

x1=1:p/m;
x2=p/m+1:2*p/m;
x3=2*p/m+1:3*p/m;

y1=m*x1;
y2=-m*x2+2*p;
y3=m*x3-2*p;

plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
```

[image]

Comment: does it actually produce any zigzag line? my r2007a doesn't

Comment: Ok, @Manex is right also, of course. Now I have a little more time, so i fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with a simple mathematical formula for zig-zag line plotting in matlab. Just copy the following line and see the majic :)

```
x = [1:100];
P = 100;
m = 5;
y=(-1).^(floor(x*m/(P))).*m.*(x-(2*P/m)*floor((floor(x*m/(P))+1)/2));
figure;plot(x,y);
```